# Given a QTableWidgetItem, how do you set its column() return value?

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing

I am trying to unit test some C++ Qt code that contains an if-statement on the value of QTableWidgetItem::column(), like this:

```
void on_resultsTable_currentItemChanged(QTableWidgetItem* currentItem, QTableWidgetItem* previousItem)
{
    if (currentItem != nullptr)
    {
        int column = currentItem->column();
        if (column == 0)
        {
            // Column0SpecificBehavior();
        }
    }
}
```

In order to test this function for the tests cases where column() == 0 and column() != 0, I need to create two QTableWidgetItem instances, one with column() 0 and one with column() 1.

I have tried this as a possible way to make QTableWidgetItem::column() return 0 instead of its default -1:

```
QTableWidget table;
table.insertRow(0);
QTableWidgetItem currentItem("Row0Column0");
table.setItem(0, 0, &currentItem);
```

But the above code results in currentItem's column() still returning -1.

Any ideas on how to set the return value of QTableWidgetItem::column()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to insert a column to your table. Your code should look like:

```
QTableWidget table;
table.insertRow(0);
table.insertColumn(0); <--- missing line
QTableWidgetItem currentItem("Row0Column0");
table.setItem(0, 0, &currentItem);

QTableWidgetItem *it = table.currentItem();
int column = it->column(); <--- this is the current column == 0
```